# How can I calculate lift curves and decile lift charts using "_xgb.Booster" "model_fit" objects rendered from parsnip function boost_tree?

Tags: r, tidymodels

I have this code that renders "_xgb.Booster" "model_fit" object classes. I should, but I am not sure how to provide the entire reproducible example code with data here!

```
xgb <- boost_tree(mode = "classification",

                      trees = 100,
                      mtry = 0.7,
                      learn_rate = 0.15,
                      tree_depth = 10,
                      sample_size = 1) %>%
      set_engine("xgboost") %>%
      fit(Y ~ ., data = train)
```

How can I calculate the lift curves and decile lift charts using this xgb object?

Comment: please make this into reproducible example as stated in the `r` tag wiki https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your data in the form such as what is in the example dataset `two_class_example`, you can use the [`lift_curve()`](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/lift_curve.html) function to compute this. Then you can make visualizations with the lift curve.

```r
library(tidymodels)

two_class_lift <- two_class_example %>%
  lift_curve(truth, Class1) 

two_class_lift %>%
  autoplot()
```

[image]

```r
two_class_lift %>%
  group_by(.percent_tested = cut_interval(.percent_tested, n = 10)) %>%
  summarise(.lift = mean(.lift, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(.percent_tested, .lift)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "% Tested", y = "Lift")
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

If you need help getting predictions out of your xgboost model, [check out this article at `tidymodels.org`](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/resampling/#performance).